# How to order data using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have tried to order this data below by occur, I used code from microsoft I get a couple of errors, I would like to know how people would tackle this? Thanks.

```
 List<Alpha> letters = new List<Alpha>
        {
            new Alpha {letter ='A', occur = new List<int>{A}},
            new Alpha {letter ='B', occur = new List<int>{B}},
            new Alpha {letter ='C', occur = new List<int>{C}},
            new Alpha {letter ='D', occur = new List<int>{D}},
            new Alpha {letter ='E', occur = new List<int>{E}},
            new Alpha {letter ='F', occur = new List<int>{F}},
            new Alpha {letter ='G', occur = new List<int>{G}},
            new Alpha {letter ='H', occur = new List<int>{H}},
            new Alpha {letter ='I', occur = new List<int>{I}},
            new Alpha {letter ='J', occur = new List<int>{J}},
            new Alpha {letter ='K', occur = new List<int>{K}},
            new Alpha {letter ='L', occur = new List<int>{L}},
            new Alpha {letter ='M', occur = new List<int>{M}},
            new Alpha {letter ='N', occur = new List<int>{N}},
            new Alpha {letter ='O', occur = new List<int>{O}},
            new Alpha {letter ='P', occur = new List<int>{P}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Q', occur = new List<int>{Q}},
            new Alpha {letter ='R', occur = new List<int>{R}},
            new Alpha {letter ='S', occur = new List<int>{S}},
            new Alpha {letter ='T', occur = new List<int>{T}},
            new Alpha {letter ='U', occur = new List<int>{U}},
            new Alpha {letter ='V', occur = new List<int>{V}},
            new Alpha {letter ='W', occur = new List<int>{W}},
            new Alpha {letter ='X', occur = new List<int>{X}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Y', occur = new List<int>{Y}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Z', occur = new List<int>{Z}},

        };
```

i do not have typos, they are actually names of varibles, these varibles hold numbers hence the "INT" thought that would have been ovbious, sorry, this question was to see how you would order the numbers i.e the occur. cheers

Comment: When asking a question, it is always a good idea to say exactly what errors you got.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile because of many typos such as `A` instead of `'A'` , `B` instead of `'B'`,  etc. After fixing typos, you actually have an ordered collection:

```
List<Alpha> letters = new List<Alpha>
        {
            new Alpha {letter ='A', occur = new List<int>{'A'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='B', occur = new List<int>{'B'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='C', occur = new List<int>{'C'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='D', occur = new List<int>{'D'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='E', occur = new List<int>{'E'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='F', occur = new List<int>{'F'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='G', occur = new List<int>{'G'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='H', occur = new List<int>{'H'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='I', occur = new List<int>{'I'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='J', occur = new List<int>{'J'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='K', occur = new List<int>{'K'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='L', occur = new List<int>{'L'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='M', occur = new List<int>{'M'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='N', occur = new List<int>{'N'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='O', occur = new List<int>{'O'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='P', occur = new List<int>{'P'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Q', occur = new List<int>{'Q'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='R', occur = new List<int>{'R'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='S', occur = new List<int>{'S'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='T', occur = new List<int>{'T'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='U', occur = new List<int>{'U'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='V', occur = new List<int>{'V'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='W', occur = new List<int>{'W'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='X', occur = new List<int>{'X'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Y', occur = new List<int>{'Y'}},
            new Alpha {letter ='Z', occur = new List<int>{'Z'}},

        };
```

If those letters haven't been already sorted:

```
var sortedLetters = 
        from p in letters 
        orderby p.letter 
        select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your typos, this should work for you:

```
var sortedLetters  =  (from c in letters select c).OrderBy(d=>d.letter)
```